# How to bring up WiFi Direct stack on ubuntu

Tags: wireless, p2p

I am working on a project where I have to connect a linux laptop with an android tablet using wifi direct.The tablet already has the wifi direct option but the laptop doesnt.
Can someone please tell what is the procedure I need to follow to get Wifi direct working on my laptop.

I am using samsung NP-R528 laptop with ubuntu 12.04.

---

Edit:
I have figured out that i have to install wpa_supplicant and wpa_cli to use p2p commands http://thangamaniarun.wordpress.com/2013/03/03/how-to-use-wi-fi-direct-on-androidubuntu-part1/
I followed the process given in the following link
http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/OMAP_Wireless_Connectivity_NLCP_WiFi_Direct_Configuration_Scripts
But when I try to connect(using p2p_connect pin keypad) it to my andorid tablet the followin happens

on linux machine it shows
GO_NEG_SUCCESS , P2p-GROUP-FORMATION-SUCCESS ,P2P-GROUP-STARTED ,WPS-SUCCESS  and then immediately CTRL-EVENT-EAP-FAILURE #android's MAC#  , AP-STA-CONNECTED #android's MAC#,  AP-STA-DISCONNECTED #android's MAC#

When i use adb to see log cat it also shows the same thing that group is formed and then immediately P2P-GROUP-REMOVED.

same thing happened when I tried the other way round(i.e. form android to ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured that The problem was caused because of the dhcp server not responding.I have found a temporary fix by assigning a static IP address to both the devices.